# Best practice for returning type from SQL Server to ExecuteScalar?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, executescalar

In C# `SqlCommand - ExecuteScalar` is :

```
private object CompleteExecuteScalar(SqlDataReader ds, bool returnSqlValue)
```

now let's go to SQL Server.

If I want to return a value from the select (which goes to `ExecuteScalar`), e.g. :

```
if record already exists select `-1`
else select `0`
```

Question :

what is the preferred (by best practices) type for returning from SQL Server  in order to reduce the amount of casting  & tostring() in C#:

```
if exists(select ....) select '-1'       -- string
```

or

```
if exists(select ....) select -1         -- int
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning number so `int` is preferable here by meaning.

Futher more, when parsing error in C# code you will be albe to do somethinng like:

```
enum Error { NO_ERROR = -1, ERROR 1 };

....

Error e = (Error)cmd.ExcecuteScalar();
```

Which is pretty clean and self explaining code as oposite to parsing result to int, or comparing string values.